# Qt QNetworkAccessManager and multiple QNetworkReply

Tags: qt, http, web, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have two get QNetworkRequest.

I want to handle finished signals from different methods.

For example this is code in

```
  MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    GetUserData();
    connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(GetUserDataCompleted(QNetworkReply*)));

    GetMessages();
    connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(GetMessagesCompleted(QNetworkReply*)));
}
```

This my one method

I have tried replay->deleteLater(); but same result

Please advice me something useful

```
void MainWindow::GetUserDataCompleted(QNetworkReply *replay)
{
    if(replay->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        QString getData = replay->readAll();
        QMessageBox msg;

        if(getData == "1")
        {
            msg.setText("User Is not Exits");
        }
        else
        {
            QDomDocument doc;

            if(doc.setContent(getData))
            {
                QDomElement domElem = doc.documentElement();

                QDomNode n = domElem.firstChild();
                while(!n.isNull()) {
                    QDomElement e = n.toElement(); // try to convert the node to an element.
                    if(!e.isNull()) {
                        msg.setText(e.namedItem("Image").childNodes().at(0).nodeValue());
                        msg.exec();
                    }
                    n = n.nextSibling();
                }
            }

            replay->deleteLater();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question? result? Is "connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(GetUserDataCompleted(QNetworkReply*)));" located inside GetUserData() and GetMessages()? OR inside a same function?

Comment: No Its They are inside MainWindow constructor see my updated question

Comment: What is your expected result? And what is your current result? Btw, you don't need to connect twice, one is enough. However, it won't effect the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a `RequestSender` class whose role is looking after requests.

Each `RequestSender` object will handle one unique request. While creating the `QNetworkRequest` that will be sent, the `RequestSender` will "tag" its own request with the `originatingObject` attribute. This attribute indicates which object sent the request. When a `RequestSender` object receives a reply, it will look if it is the sender of the request via the `originatingObject` attribute. For further informations about `originatingObject`, you can refer to the documentation here : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkrequest.html#originatingObject

Below is an example of what you can do.

requestsender.hpp :

```
class RequestSender {
    public:
        RequestSender();
        ~RequestSender();
        void createRequest(/* Request parameters */);

    public slots:
        void endRequest(QNetworkReply* replay);
};
```

requestsender.cpp :

```
RequestSender::RequestSender() {
    connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(endRequest(QNetworkReply*)));
}

RequestSender::~RequestSender() {
    disconnect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(endRequest(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void RequestSender::createRequest(/* Request parameters */) {
    QNetworkRequest * myRequest = 0;

    // Build myRequest with the request parameters

    myRequest->setOriginatingObject(this);
    nam->get(*myRequest);

}

void RequestSender::endRequest(QNetworkReply* replay) {
    if (replay->request().originatingObject() != this) {
        // That's not the request sent by the object -> stop the method here !
        return;
    }

    // Treatments on replay
}
```

Comment: Love this solution, also your profile pic 

Answer (score 2):

Every operation you do with your QNetworkAccessManager will return a QNetworkReply. This has also has an signal finished(). Maybe you can connect this signal to your different slots.