# QNetworkAccessManager: Associate response with request

Tags: qt, rest, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager

I try to do a simple GET to a REST Service and want to know how I can identify/associate the request to the response I get in my SLOT function. For example I might send multiple requests the same manager and want to pass a messageID in order to read that ID in my SLOT function to associate the response with the responsible request.

Any ideas how to do this?

```
QNetworkAccessManager manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply)),
this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://qt-project.org")));
```

Comment: Here's one approach; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077211/qt-qnetworkaccessmanager-and-multiple-qnetworkreply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answere: The reply provides a function that returns the request: [`QNetworkReply::request()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#request)...

Try to check the documention first next time.

**EDIT:**
If you need more data than that, you have various ways of doing that. For example you could add the data as a dynamic property to the request (see [`QObject::setProperty`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty)) or store the `QNetworkReply` returned by `QNetworkAccessManager::get` function inside a `QHash` with the data you need.

Comment: but can I also pass some metadata to the request object? The original request is not enough when I send multipe equal requests.

Comment: QNetworkRequest is not an QObject so setProperty is not available.

Comment: @PredragManojlovic my bad - I meant the reply. Fixed the answer

Answer (score 2):

you could use c++11 bindings:

```
QNetworkAccessManager manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply)), this, 
SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
QNetworkRequest *request = new QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://qt-project.org"));
QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request );
QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, std::bind(&YOURCLASS::onGetFinished, this, reply, request));

void YOURCLASS::onGetFinished( QNetworkReply* reply, QNetworkRequest* request ) {}
```